# VMware auto-reboots on login

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware

I have a Ubuntu 14 running on VMware on my Windows 10 Dell laptop.

For the past few days I have been facing this problem. Whenever I try to login, it accepts my credentials loads the home page and loads the login screen page again. I tried doing a guest login but the same thing happened.

The `vmware.log` file in the Virtual Machines folder read

```
DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "C:\ProgramData\VMware\VMware Workstation\config.ini": The system cannot find the file specified

ConfigDB: Failed to load C:\ProgramData\VMware\VMware Workstation\config.ini

DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "C:\ProgramData\VMware\VMware Workstation\settings.ini": The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I checked the file path, there is nothing in the folder. I haven't made any changes to any setting. What can be done on this situation?

Comment: If you type the Alt and F2 keys together and get to a console window, can you then login OK, or is there an error message?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Yaa I did login through the console. It did not give me any error.

Comment: After logging in, look in the `.xsession-errors` file in your home directory for any errors. Programs that aren't found, cannot be executed, get permission denied errors, segmentation violations, that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the VMWare documentation [here](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1754), it says that you can just create a blank `config.ini` file. Doing a quick Google search gives me some [old Workstation 5 documentation](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_special_config.html) that says there are some required fields that should be present in `config.ini`:

```
mks.ctlAltDel.ignore = "TRUE"
mks.fullscreen.allowScreenSaver = "TRUE"
fullScreenSwitch.onSeparateDesktop = "TRUE"
msg.autoAnswer = "TRUE"
```

I haven't seen anything in the current knowledge base that says anything about required fields in the file.

I would just reinstall VMWare and let the installer handle it. It's not going to remove any of your virtual machines, if that's a concern.

Comment: I did put in these details in the `config.ini` file but still it doesn't open. Asks me to login again even if i put in the credentials.

Comment: Are you still seeing the `config.ini` errors in your log? This file doesn't have anything to do with your VM not logging in properly. I was only attempting to help you solve your `config.ini` problem since you mentioned that being in your logs. That way you're not seeing any more errors about `config.ini`, possibly confusing yourself and thinking that's the error.